# How to add rows from Textboxes to a gridview ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to add rows to a gridview with information coming from a TextBox and a DropDownList here i have my gridview tag

```
<asp:GridView  style="width: 80%" align="center" id="gridview" runat="server" ForeColor="#333333"></asp:GridView>
```

So whenever I try to add a new row it creates the first one correctly but when I change the data from the TextBox and from the DroDownList it substitutes the first one already created instead of creating a new one.

Here is my codebehind:

```
int id=1;
string nombre= platillo.Text; 
string pais=Lista_paises.SelectedItem.Value;

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Pais", typeof(string));

DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
NewRow[0] = id;
NewRow[1] = nombre;
NewRow[2] = pais; 
dt.Rows.Add(NewRow); 
gridview.DataSource = dt;
gridview.DataBind();
id++;
```

Comment: can you please update with all code and event as well

Comment: You creating new datatable and filling grid with it every time. You need to have only one datatable assigned to grid and [append that datatable with new record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-data-to-a-datatable).

Comment: `id++` does nothing unless you store it in a Session or ViewState.

Comment: I use `id++` so the ID column will be increased automatically with every row created